# Accessing pixel using x,y coordinate in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, pixel

I have the following Javascript code-

```
var img=new SimpleImage('image.png');
```

The dimension of the ***image.png*** file is **10x10**. Now I need to access the pixel at coordinate (5,4) and get it's Red value. I've googled but cannot find a way to access the pixel using it's coordinate. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the image onto a canvas, use [ctx.createImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) to get the image data.

Excerpt copied from MDN

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/KM2bAUL.jpeg';
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 300);
  img.style.display = 'none';
};
var color = document.getElementById('color');
function pick(event) {
  var x = event.layerX;
  var y = event.layerY;
  var pixel = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
  var data = pixel.data;
  var rgba = 'rgba(' + data[0] + ', ' + data[1] +
             ', ' + data[2] + ', ' + (data[3] / 255) + ')';
  color.style.background =  rgba;
  color.textContent = rgba;
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', pick);
```

```html
<div id="color">I will change</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="400px"></canvas>
```